# Get first n elements of each parent in jQuery

Tags: jquery, hide, html-lists

If a page has many ul lists with various children, is there an easy way to only show the first five for each ul item, for instance?  I know I can give each ul tag a unique id and then do like `$("ul#id1 li").slice(5).hide();` for each one, or get all of them and then use a javascript loop to go over each particular one, but it seems like there should be an easier way.  Thanks.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/slice/ If you use it properly it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you will need a loop, since you are talking about addressing multiple ULs in one go:

```
$("ul").each(function () {
    $(this).find("li:gt(4)").hide(); 
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/AhYpN/)

Comment: I had already found this method as mentioned in my question but after further review, I believe this is the simplest way.  Thanks!